# Chmod in Shell Script does not work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, console, chmod, chown

i am running a small server using Ubuntu 12.04. I am logged in as a non-root user via SSH public key authentication. This server runs apache which is supposed to run a symfony2 website.

I want to write a shell script that ensures that every file and directory in my symfony2 app has the right owner and the right access rights. The script I use is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

chown -R www-data:www-data portal    
chmod -R 755 portal    
php portal/bin/console cache:clear --env=dev    
php portal/bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

The script has been granted the exec right via chmod +x setup (setup is the name of the script)

I try to execute it as an root via ./setup.
There are no error messages displayed. But after running it the chown and chmod does not seem to work. the owner is still the same (root:root)

If I execute these commands manually in the console they work.

Why is this? What can I do to solve the problem?

Kind regards
Thomas

Comment: Does nobody have any ideas?

Comment: Ich habe den Fehler. Das Kommando von Symfony war schuld! Das ändert sebst die Besitzrechte vom cache... Und da ich immer als root ausgeführt habe, wurde auch symfony als root ausgeführt. somit war immer root der Besitzer und nicht www-data

Comment: Does it work if you add a `cd` command to enter the relevant directory before executing the `chown` and `chmod` commands?